# como exibir chaves no browser?

Tags: javascript, html, react

Olá, quero exibir uma palavra porém com "{}" exemplo {palavra}

segue parte do código em questão

```js
function LogoCovid() {
  return (
    <LogoStyle>
       Dev {palavra}
    </LogoStyle>
```

> Citação

Já tentei colocar entre ('," e sem `<string>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem, você quer escrever os caracteres `'{'` e `'}'` literalmente, se for esse o caso, basta escrever dessa forma:

```
 {'{' + Luciane + '}'}
```

Comment: é isso mesmo. Obrigada

Answer (score -3):

Basta setar a tag title do seu html.

Segue um exemplo:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Luciane</title>


</head>

<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```